# Wordpress Multisite SMTP

Tags: wordpress, smtp, gmail

I run several sites in a Wordpress Multisite environment. Everything runs great, except when it comes to SMTP. I'm using Digital Ocean as my cloud server, and the php_mail() functionality isn't enough to do what I need it to do. It has gotten my IP blocked in the past too.

So what I do, if a client needs a mail form, is I have the WP SMTP plugin installed, which will send the mail on my behalf. The problem is, in order to use it with SPF verification, it needs to be connected to a Google account. So I have to use my own personal gmail account for this. It works, but the sender is always my personal email address, for all of my sites. This is not the look I want.

So the question is, is there an SMTP service I can use that doesn't require my personal email address?

Comment: Can't some plugin use an unique SMTP config for each Multisite single site? I don't understand why you're using a global config for all sites... A solution would be using an embedded 3rd party form. Btw, I also can't see how the question is on-topic for SO